# How to force Visual Studio to use absolute "Output path" for C# projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

If you set an absolute `Ouput path` in Visual Studio it's always turned into a relative path:

Before:

```
C:\Bin\Debug\MyApp
```

After

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\Bin\Debug\MyApp
```

However on different machines my solutions are in different folders and the `Output path` won't work anymore if I don't use the default one which is the `bin\Debug`.

Can I somehow force Visual Studio to use an absolute `Ouput path`?

Comment: Accidentally I discovered a similar question today while looking for general MSBuild help.